# Combining Qt6 and VTK9.2 on MacOS

Tags: qt, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to use VTK in a Qt6 application. I've successfully been able to use it in a Qt5 application, but want to move to Qt6.

I am on MacOS Ventura (13.2.1). There I have installed Qt5.15.2 and Qt6.4.2 via Qt Creator. Both work fine.

However, when I try to combine with VTK (9.2, installed via homebrew), it only seems to play nice with Qt5. If I add `find_package(VTK 9.2 REQUIRED)` to my `CMakeLists.txt`, and then try to compile the app using Qt6, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:115 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
  version 5.15) with any of the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/vtk-config.cmake:155 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
```

So it seems to want a reference to Qt5, even though that should not be necessary if I'm building a Qt6 app, right? Looking into the `VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake` file, line 115 reads:

```
 find_package(Qt5
    5.15
```

so there seems to be some hard-coded reference to Qt5 in my VTK install. Did I do something wrong during the installation of VTK? (I just typed `brew install vtk`) Or is Qt6 not yet supported? According to [this thread](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/how-to-get-vtk9-qt6-working-together/4927/13), support should be included from VTK 9.1 onward. But they talk about configuring it during the VTK CMake process. How do I do that? Is that maybe not possible using homebrew?

Comment: Have you tried to run `ccmake .` (or the CMake GUI) in the build directory (where the CMakeCache file is located) and set the variable `VTK_QT_VERSION` to Qt6?

Answer (score 1):

As of August 1st, 2023, brew's VTK package has [switched to Qt6](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/d16947c4bc97fdbec17ca158713f3609b701a4a4). Thus, this question is no longer a problem anymore.

Furthermore, VTK8 has also been disabled. Thus, as of August 2023, there is no VTK package in Homebrew that still has a Qt5 dependency anymore. Unfortunately, this creates the inverse problem - existing Qt5 programs cannot be built anymore until they're ported to Qt6. For now, building VTK from source with Qt5 via MacPorts is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build VTK yourself linked against Qt6 if brew doesn't offer a version which is build against it.

vcpkg for example offers VTK build against Qt6.